# How to use load balancing in amazon when database server is separate instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

We have this configuration for our website

Application server -- m1.small

Database server -- m1.medium

Content Server -- m1.large

API Server -- t1.micro

How to use the existing instance to integrate with the elastic load balancing with auto scaling?

Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much completely up to you. Are you using RDS for the database? Or is it a custom ec2 instance. In either case, you can't fully 'load balance' the database. But you can have replication setup ready for failover if there's a problem. I recommend RDS because they make this very easy. You can also setup read-only replicas which you can use to distribute load for read operations.

For the other servers, you need to setup launch configurations, and scaling groups for the servers, with load balancers attached. Then, you can scale up your pool of servers and the load balancer will start sending traffic to the new server.

You have to make sure that the servers themselves don't contain any important information - all data should be written into the database, so that you can scale up and down as needed. When you scale down, all information on the terminated servers will be lost.